# .htaccess rewrite #

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a url to an anchor tag like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /subpage http://domain.com/#subpage
```

With this the new URL looks like this:

```
http://comain.com/%23subpage
```

How do I keep the # Anchor sign?

Edit: Where do I have to put the NE Tag in my code?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch 301 /subpage http://domain.com/#subpage
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Comment: Well, the `[NE]` flag belongs at the end of the `RedirectMatch` line. Could it be you are using a very old version of apache that does not yet support flags on the `RedirectMatch` directive? Also note that the `RedirectMatch` directive is _not_ provided by `mod_rewrite`, but by `mod_alias`. You only test if `mod_rewrite` is loaded, you will have to test for `mod_alias` too...

Comment: Looks like mod_alias isn't enabled on my server :(

Comment: You can 'emulare' the `RedirectMatch` directive using `mod_rewrite'.

Answer (score 0):

A simple lookup in the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html) reveals:

```
Use the [NE] flag on the RewriteRule. NE stands for No Escape.
```

You surely could have done that lookup yourself, couldn't you?

Comment: Yes. but where the heck do I have to put this NE? I tried several places, but it doesn't work nowhere.